# favorite script with local storage don't work

Tags: javascript

I want to add data-id from a button in favorite list.
I tried few solution but the click action is never detected in console .

html code is

```html
<button class="icon-plus-circle i-circled i-small addToCart" date-id="myId" data-name="myName"></button>
```

js code is

```
button.addEventListener('click', function (){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');

    console.log(id);

    let Fav  = {
        id : id ,
        name : name
    };
    let liste_json = JSON.stringify(Fav);

    localStorage.setItem('listeFavoris', JSON.stringify(liste_json));
} )
```

Comment: html code <button class="icon-plus-circle i-circled i-small addToCart" date-id="myId" data-name="myName"></button>

Comment: Could you show the query you use to retrieve the button element in your Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the button

`const button = document.querySelector('button');`

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click detected');
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

PS - You have added `click` listener using `javascript` and have `jQuery` code inside. Don't mix up two, stick with one.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have an error : jQuery.Deferred exception: button is null

Comment: @OlivierLyonnais - It works in snippet. Check whether you are passing it correctly or not `document.querySelector('button')`.